# How to extract data from JSON file for each entry?

Tags: python, json, csv, parsing

So I am using the JSON package in python to extract data from generated JSON which would essentially fetched data from a firebase database which was then  generated as a JSON file.

Within the given data set I want to extract all of the data corresponding to bills in each entry within the JSON file. For that I created a separate dictionary to add all of the elements corresponding to bills in the dataset.

When converted to CSV, the dataset looks like this:

[csv for one entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Mr1c.png)
So I have the following code to do above operation. But as I create a new dictionary, there are certain entries which have null values designated as `[]` (see the csv file). I assigned list to store all those bills which would have the data in the bills column (essentially avoiding all the null entries). But as a I create a new list the required output is only getting stored in the first index of the new list or array. Please see the code below.

My code is as below:

```
filedata = open('requireddataset.json','r') data = json.load(filedata)
listoffields = []   # To produce it into a list with fields  for dic
for dic in data:
    try:
        listoffields.append(dic['bills'])   # only non-essential bill categories.
    except KeyError:
        pass
#print (listoffields[3])   # This would return the first payment entry within 
                           # the JSON Array of objects.

for val in listoffields:
    if val!=[]:
        x = val[0]   # only val[0] would contain data
        #print (x)
        myarray = np.array(val)
        print(myarray[0])  # All of the data stored in only one index, any way to change this?
```

This is the output : [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeIlI.png)
This is how the original JSON file looks like : [requireddataset.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqws2.png)
Essentially my question is  the list listoffields would contain all the fields in it(from the JSON file), and bills in one of the fields. And within the column bills each entry again contains id, value, role and many other entries. Is there any way to extract only values from this and produce sum .

In the JSON file this is how it looks like for one entry :

```
 [{"goal_savings": 0.0, "social_id": "", "score": 0, "country": "BR", "photo": "http://graph.facebook", "id": "", "plates": 3, "rcu": null, "name": "", "email": ".", "provider": "facebook", "phone": "", "savings": [], "privacyPolicyAccepted": true, "currentRole": "RoleType.PERSONAL", "empty_lives_date": null, "userId": "", "authentication_token": "-------", "onboard_status": "ONBOARDING_WIZARD", "fcmToken": ----------", "level": 1, "dni": "", "social_token": "", "lives": 10, "bills": [{"date": "2020-12-10", "role": "RoleType.PERSONAL", "name": "Supermercado", "category": "feeding", "periodicity": "PeriodicityType.NONE", "value": 100.0"}], "payments": [], "goals": [], "goalTransactions": [], "incomes": [], "achievements": [{"created_at":", "name": ""}]}]
```

Comment: The CSV doesn't have JSON in it.

Comment: JSON always uses double quotes around strings, you have single quotes in the CSV.

Comment: Yeah that's right ! Any way to extract all the values in the column bills ??

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval()`, since it looks like a Python object.

Comment: Okay thanks. so , the list listoffields would contain all the fields in it, and bills in one of the fields. And within the column bills each entry again contains id, value, role and many other entries. Is there any way to extract only values from this ?

Comment: Show the original JSON file, not the CSV you created from it.

Comment: Please see above.

Comment: Please post text, not images.

Comment: Hi Barmar, thanks for reaching out. It contains confidential info , so I cannot post the whole document. But may be one entry I can post it as text.

Comment: We don't need the actual document, just something that shows the structure.

Comment: I have added it, please see above.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Especially don't post giant ones.

Comment: Okay I understand !

Comment: Can you clarify what you are looking for by adding your desired output to the question

Comment: That data you added for one entry isn't valid JSON format, and the data shown for the `"bills"` key is not valid Python syntax (so `ast.literal_eval()` can't handle it. You need to reduce things to a the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem and fix the formatting errors.

Comment: Hi thanks for reaching out martineu. But using the syntax I am getting the output. I wonder what's wrong in that, it involves appending to a list created as far I know. May be you suggest what exact syntax do I need to modify ?

Comment: As you can see in the JSON entry, all I need to do is access bills and then extract values for all of the entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot martineu, with your level of expertise may be you are right ! :) Let me check my code again .

Comment: Hi Barmar, Are you free anytime for a video call ?

Comment: As other have mentioned, posting the content of the images as text would help me reproduce the problem. I don't want to manually type all the content into a text editor.

Comment: Will post the text of the pics .Thanks Ben , I understand that.